# Ascending ArrayList is adding element in wrong order

Tags: java, recursion

I have a list that is comparing the column elements of an `ArrayList` (essentially, the string word of an ArrayList that contains string lines).

I was able to read the column part correctly, but there's an error for my insertion method (which I'm doing recursively).

For instance, when it finds a word that is smaller than the previous word, instead of inserting it before the bigger word, it inserts it at the beginning of the `ArrayList`. I'm not exactly sure why this is, as I seem to be following the steps for insertion exactly what my notes say. Can anyone see why this is happening?

```
//line is just a string separated by commas
private void insertSorted(String line){
//memFile is the ArrayList
if(memFile.isEmpty()){
  memFile.add(0,line); 
}
else{
 for(int i = memFile.size() - 1; i >=0 ; i--){
    int index = i;
    String lineList = memFile.get(i);
    String[] tokens = line.trim().split(",");

    String lineList = memFile.get(i);

    String[] tokens1 = lineList.trim().split(",");
     //column is the part I want to compare of the tokenized string
   while(index >= 0){
    if((tokens[column]).compareTo(tokens1[column]) < 0)
      index--;
     }
     break;
    }
    memFile.add(index+1,line);
    System.out.println("memFile is " + memFile);

  }//for
 }//else
}//insertSorted
```

It's printing out:

`3
 1
 2
 2
 4
 1`

as

`1
 2
 2
 3
 1
 4`

Edit:
Say I had an `ArrayList memfile`, and it contained the strings:

" 1,DOG,Airplane"

" 3,HAT,Basket"

And I wanted to sort the third variables by alphabetically order. Then I would tokenize the `string`, and from the main method, I would call 2 (column is an instance variable I declared making this class). So, then it would search for tokens[col], or, equivalently, tokens[2].

Comment: Please post verifiable code - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you want the list to be sorted based on the `col`th value in each element of the list?

Comment: @Kishore, `col` is just a number just specifies which column I want to my `ArrayList` to be sorted by. Say I said, `"FileUtil fUtil1 = new FileUtil(0);"`, then I would want the `ArrayList` to be sorted by its integers in ascending order. If I said, `"FileUtil fUtil1 = new FileUtil(1);"`, then I would want it to be sorted by DOG, and HAT. Does that make sense? I'm not the best at explaining. But my code works, it just seems that when it finds a smaller value, instead of placing the line containing the element to the left of the bigger line, it places it at the beginning of the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic mistake in your method, what you are doing is comparing the `line` with the last value of the `memFile` instead of comparing the current `index` line of the `memFile` when reducing the `index`

Here i modified the method according to your required logic.

```
private void insertSorted(String line) {
    // memFile is the ArrayList
    if (memFile.isEmpty()) {
        memFile.add(0, line);
    } else {
        int index = memFile.size() - 1;

        String[] tokens = line.trim().split(",");

        // column is the part I want to compare of the tokenized string
        while (index >= 0) {
            String lineList = memFile.get(index);

            String[] tokens1 = lineList.trim().split(",");

            if ((tokens1[column]).compareTo(tokens[column]) > 0) {
                index--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        memFile.add(index + 1, line);
        System.out.println("memFile is " + memFile);

    }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thank-you!! I'm still confused as to why I can't compare the last `line` in `memFile` though. Are you saying that if I was comparing `Advanced, Basket, Potato, Planes,` `Planes` would just compare with `Potato` and not the other ones in the list?

Comment: Exactly, using a paper and pencil try your previous method with sample test case to know what is happening in the method and for your information your method is not a `recursion`.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, and have the current element compare with each element in the `ArrayList`, and not just the most recent one in it, but it seems to just mess up my code a bit. I'll edit my post to show you what I mean.

Comment: i checked your test case and found a mistake in my code, i edited it to give  the expected result, check my modified answer.